# Serialize to an XML document without overwriting previous data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization

I need to serialize to an XML document without overwriting the data that is currently in there. I have a method that does this and it will save to the xml file, but will delete whatever is currently in that file upon serializing. Below is the code.

```
public void SaveSubpart()
    {
        SOSDocument doc = new SOSDocument();
        doc.ID = 1;
        doc.Subpart = txtSubpart.Text;
        doc.Title = txtTitle.Text;
        doc.Applicability = txtApplicability.Text;
        doc.Training = txtTraining.Text;
        doc.URL = txtUrl.Text;

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Contents.xml"));
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;
        try
        {
            serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(doc.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(writer, doc);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //e-mail admin - serialization failed
        }
        finally
        { writer.Close(); }
    }
```

Comment: Read xml, append new items and then save...

Comment: **If the file exists, it is overwritten** ([MSDN: StreamWriter Constructor (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx), look under `Remarks`)

Comment: So there is no way to add a single node when serializing?

Answer (score 2):

[The contract for the `StreamWriter` constructor taking only a filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx) says that if the named file exists, it is overwritten. So this has nothing to do with serializing to XML, per se. You would get the same result if you wrote to the stream through some other means.

**The way to do what you are looking for is to read the old XML file into memory, make whatever changes are necessary, and then serialize and write the result to disk.**

And even if it was possible to transparently modify an on-disk XML file, that's almost certainly what would happen under the hood because it's the only way to really do it. Yes, you probably *could* fiddle around with seeking and writing directly on disk, but what if something caused the file to change on disk while you were doing that? If you do the read/modify/write sequence, then you lose out on the changes that were made after you read the file into memory; but if you modify the file directly on disk by seeking and writing, you would be almost guaranteed to end up with the file in an inconsistent state.

And of course, you could only do it if you could fit whatever changes you wanted to make into the bytes that were already on disk...

If concurrency is a problem, either use file locking or use a proper database with transactional support.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Contents.xml"),true);
```

this determines to append the data to the file.

true=append,
false = overwrite

more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

Comment: That will ad it but it adds the root node as well. I just need the fields to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to implement is to serialize an object without overwriting it to an existing file.

Thus

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(doc.GetType());
TextWriter w = new StringWriter();
s.Serialize(w, doc);
var yourXMLstring = w.ToString();
```

Then you can process this xml string and append it to existing xml file if you want to.

```
 XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
 xml.LoadXml(yourXMLstring );
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that (at least if done naiively) it will almost certainly result in an incorrect XML document, because the entire XML document must be contained within a single outermost tag. So you have to have `<data>...</data>`, you cannot have `<data>...</data> <data>...</data>` or any variant thereof.